# Какая парадигма обработки ошибок лучше?

Tags: c++, обработка-ошибок

Имеется в виду С++, естественно.

1. С использованием блоков **try**{} **catch**{} и операции **throw**
2. С помощью **return**?
3. Какой-либо другой способ?

Очень интересуют Ваши мнения по данному вопросу.

Comment: Используя исключения, важно не увлекаться и не использовать исключения для управления порядком исполнения (*control flow*) резервируя исключения для исключительных ситуаций.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все методы хороши. Но они сильно от задачи зависят.

- обработка ошибок должна быть однообразна (как минимум в пределах одной библиотеки).
- высоконагруженный код лучше обрабатывать через код ошибки (у Вас это вариант 2). Причина банальна - больше контроля (но при неверном подходе, когда if добавляются на каждый чих, скорость может даже просесть, а сам код превратиться в лапшу).
- Обычный код (например gui), достаточно хорошо обрабатывается try{} catch{}  - здесь уже не скорость важна, а адекватная реакция (хотя, если код будет обычный клик обрабатывать пол часика, ничего хорошего не будет. Но между 0.01 с и 0.001 разницы для пользователя мало).
- try{} catch{}  хорош, когда исключения будут происходить редко. Очень редко. Но если они произошли, то все, приплыли. В некоторых реализациях try{} catch{}  очень дешевый, если исключение не происходит. Да и код прозрачнее получается.
- Существуют случаи, когда нельзя применять try{} catch{}. Например на symbian. Там просто компилятор их не понимает (хотя может в последних версиях все поправили).

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы KoVadim. Позволю тоже дать свой совет: используйте конструкцию try{} catch{} с обязательной проверкой кода ошибки (как возможно, но не для всех исключений:). Для критически важных ошибок ставьте свой обработчик, а для остальных сделайте универсал). Все зависит от приложения, которое вы разрабатываете.

Comment: @Вячеслав Кириченко Эксепшны с проверкой кода ошибки? Масло масляное?)

Comment: Собственно, клиентский код, обрабатывающий исключения ничуть не компактнее кода, обрабатывающего статус возврата. Прикиньте ради примера распределение чего-либо в куче, передача указателя функции и предотвращение утечки в случае чего.

Comment: видимо имеется ввиду, что на каждый тип ошибки нужно завести свой тип exception и иметь не один универсальный catch, а несколько.

Comment: Ценные замечания - сильно от задачи (приложения) зависит.

В самом деле, некоторые приложения никакой обработкой ошибок не поправить.

--

По делу. В С++ мне больше нравится проверка кода возврата+флагов, а вот в Java с ее сбором мусора (или наоборот - кучами мусора) try/catch/finally весьма органичны.

Comment: Никто не может мне подсказать в чем дело, если при попытке обработать выбрасываемое исключение программа зависает (входит в вечный цикл)?

Comment: То вот все тестовое задание, никак не могу доделать. Ибо в ТЗ явно намекается, что надо использовать Try catch но с ним программа виснет. Кстати, в том же ТЗ написали, что нужно заностить в лог исключение, связанное с ошибкой вызова функции возврата времени, а как его в ней ловить если в той функции все вызываемые ф-ии стандартные и исключений никаких не выбрасывают?

Comment: @pol500,

  а как его в ней ловить если в той функции все вызываемые ф-ии стандартные и исключений никаких не выбрасывают?

Оберните *ту функцию* своей, анализируйте коды возврата и вбрасывайте исключение.

--

По поводу зацикливания - гляньте отладчиком, потом анализируйте код.